# Сообщение о ошибке валидации даты Flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Есть такая форма

```
class MeetForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Название встречи', [validators.Length(min=6, max=25, message='От 6 до 25 символов')])
    date = DateField('Дата встречи', format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

Как видите, если название встречи находиться вне диапазона `[6; 25]` символов, то пользователь получит ошибку, которую увидит под `input` формы.

Теперь о дате. Если дата будет, допустим, `26.04.17` (а не `24.04.2017`) то форма валидацию не пройдет (все верно), но пользователь *не увидит ошибки*.

(Во всяком случае, поведение при ошибке будет не такое, как при ошибке в названии встречи).

У валидатора `Length` есть поле `message`, а как быть с сообщением о некорректности *даты*?

UPD:
Привожу код обработчика формы

```
@app.route('/make', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def _make_meet():
    form = MeetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return 'form ok'
    return render_template('make_meet.html', form=form)
```

Если мы не правильно введем название встречи, то при отправке формы увидим следующее:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если мы правильно введем название встречи и дату, то увидим
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но! Если мы правильно введем название встречи, но неправильно введем дату, то ничего у нас не получиться. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Условие `form.validate_on_submit()` не выполниться, форма не отправиться, но ошибки мы не увидим. Как сделать так, чтобы текст ошибки выводился как в первом случае? Регулярки не хочу. Документацию по кастомным функциям валидации видел, но как прикрутить к ним `message` не понял.

Comment: «поведение при ошибке будет не такое» — а какое? Если я правильно понял исходники wtforms, должно быть сообщение об ошибке типа «Not a valid date value» (или аналог на русском). У вас сейчас так или как?

Comment: @andreymal обновил вопрос, взгляните, пожалуйста. У меня не так..

Answer (score 0):

```
date = DateField('Дата встречи', [validators.Regexp(r'^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}$', message=u'Неверный формат даты')], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: . 99.99.9999 :)

Comment: @andreymal не сложно и [свой валидатор написать](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html#custom-validators) :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, видел, но message там не увидел

Comment: @IvanBlohin `raise ValidationError('текст ошибки')`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, конечно, я так и думал) Проблема оказалась в том, что это поле я выводил ручками и бутстраповский класс добавлял самостоятельно. Т.е. фактически ошибка была, но в DOM не было блока, где бы она показывалась..